# linq-To-SQL not getting updated db data

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

i'm looping through a repeater and firing update queries to my db with the c# SqlCommand

later on when i want an entity type from the newly updated type i use

```
Document d = (from c in db.Documents where c.Id = myID select c).First();
```

i get a document where the fields that were updated use SqlCommand are still null, but when i check the db, the fields have the correct values.

is there a way to either get the entity type from an SqlCommand command, or make sure Linq-To-Sql gets updated data.

I've tried running db.savechanges() before doing this, but no difference.

EDIT:

```
SqlCommand command = getCommand(type, field, item, nDocID, required); // commandText = "UPDATE Documents SET " + field + "=@" + field + " WHERE DocumentID = " + id; "



                    if (command != null)
                    {
                        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connString"].ConnectionString);

                        command.Connection = conn;
                        conn.Open();
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conn.Close();
                    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you are updating it.

Comment: added the lines where i execute the sqlcommand

Comment: you could refresh your data context as others have suggested, but in my experience this does have a performance hit.  I think you would be better off doing all of your database interaction through Linq2Sql rather than mixing it with direct sql commands as you are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

db.SaveChanges() won't do anything because you didn't make any changes through EF to apply. The changes you made are outside its scope. I'm guessing you declared your db variable globally and EF caches data. Instead, try doing this:

```
using(somethingEntities db = new somethingEntities()){
  Document d = (from c in db.Documents where c.Id = myID select c).First();
  // do something here
}
```